# complete k-partite graphs

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Let $G$ be a nonempty graph with the property that whenever $uv \notin E(G)$ and $vw \notin E(G)$, then $uw \notin E(G)$. Prove that $G$ has this property if and only if $G$ is a complete $k$-partite graph for some $k \geq 2$. (Consider $\bar{G}$).

The converse is straightforward and is given by the definition of the complete k-partite graphs, however, the direct way is not trivial and I could not get it. Any helps? :)

Answer (score 2):

(There was a typo in your problem, the conclusion of the property must be $uw\notin E(G)$ (not $uw\in E(G)$).

First of all, each complete $k$-partite graph has this property, as you say.

To show the inverse, assume the property (whenever $uv$ and $vw$ are not edges of $g,$ then $uw$ is not an edge). Consider the relation on the vertices where two vertices are related if there is *no* edge between them (or if they are identical). This is an equivalence relation, where transitivity follows from the given property.

Per definition, given a pair of vertices from different equivalent classes there must be an edge between them. Thus, $G$ is a complete $k$-partite graph, where the decomposition of the vertices into sets (as required by the definition) is given by the equivalent classes.

Comment: Thank your for your prompt response and thanks for bringing that typo to the attention. As far as I understood from your response, you considered graph $\bar{G}$ where the the relation you defined holds true. Now, if $\bar{G}$ is a complete k-partite graph, is $G$ also a k-partite graph?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't have phrased it with $\bar G.$ My logic is simply  to observe that grouping the vertices into equivalence classes gives you the property of a $k$-partite graph (defined as in the Wikipedia). In a way, the equivalence is almost tautological.